# How do I evenly space time moments in solve_ivp (Python)?

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I want to solve a function for a given time steps, yet even after setting t_eval to be an evenly distributed arraay of moments in time, the function performs calculations for timesteps differing in size between one another (I know it might be useful, but for my purpose it has to be even).
This code:

```
t0 = 0
tf = 10
dt = 0.001

#def projectile_motion(t, y):
    #here is the function evaluated by solve_ivp
projectile_motion.t_prev = t0
sol = solve_ivp(projectile_motion, (t0, tf), [x0, y0, vx0, vy0], t_eval = np.linspace(t0, tf, int((tf-t0)/dt)+1))
```

results in function being evaluated at timesteps like 1E-8 seconds, despite the t_eval explicitly saying to do it every 10^-3 s. What can I do to make solve_ivp choose the timesteps evenly, one dt at a time?

EDIT:
The whole code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Cd = 0.47 #coefficient of drag
r = 1 #radius of the ball [meters]
A = np.pi * r**2 #cross-section area of the ball [m^2]

g = 9.81 # [m/s^2]
rho = 1.2 # air density [kg/m^3]
m_total = 27 # rocket + fuel mass [kg]
m_fuel = 4 # fuel mass [kg]
v_e =800 # velocity of gas [m/s]
v0 =1000 # muzle velocity # [m/s]
thetadeg =25 # angle between the muzzle velocity and the ground [degrees]
capacity =0.01 #amount of fuel (in kilograms) that will exit the rocket during one second when the gas speed is 1 m/s [kg/m]

theta = np.deg2rad(thetadeg)
x0 = 0
y0 = 0
vx0 = v0 * np.cos(theta)
vy0 = v0 * np.sin(theta)

t0 = 0
tf = 100
dt = 0.001

if v_e > 0 and m_fuel>0:
    fuel_duration = m_fuel/(v_e*capacity)
    m_fuel_duration = m_fuel/fuel_duration
else:
    m_fuel = 0
    m_fuel_duration = 0
    fuel_duration = 0

check = 0
check_hit = 0
x_of_fuel_out = None
x_hit = None

def projectile_motion(t, y):
    global check, x_of_fuel_out, x_hit, check_hit
    if 'm_total' not in projectile_motion.__dict__:
        projectile_motion.m_total = m_total
    x, y, vx, vy = y
    v = np.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2)
    rho_air = rho
    F_gravity = np.array([0, -projectile_motion.m_total * g])
    F_drag = -0.5 * rho_air * v**2 * Cd * A * np.array([vx, vy])/v 
    
    if 'm_fuel' not in projectile_motion.__dict__:
        projectile_motion.m_fuel = m_fuel
        projectile_motion.t_fuel = fuel_duration
        projectile_motion.fuel = 1
    if projectile_motion.m_fuel>0:
        projectile_motion.t_fuel -= dt
        projectile_motion.m_fuel -= dt*m_fuel_duration
        projectile_motion.m_total -= dt*m_fuel_duration
        momentum_fuel = v_e * dt*m_fuel_duration
        F_thrust = momentum_fuel* np.array([np.cos(theta),np.sin(theta)])/dt
    else:
        if check ==0:
            check = 1
            x_of_fuel_out = x
        if t>fuel_duration:
            projectile_motion.fuel_cutoff = t
            projectile_motion.fuel = 0
        F_thrust = np.array([0, 0])
    if y<0 and check_hit==0:
        check_hit = 1
        x_hit = x
    F_total = F_gravity + F_drag + F_thrust
    a = F_total / projectile_motion.m_total
    projectile_motion.t_prev = t
    print(f"t: {t}      x: {round(x,2)},     v: {round(vx,2)}, {round(vy,2)} ,     thrust: {round(F_thrust[0],2)}, {round(F_thrust[1],2)},     drag: {round(F_drag[0],2)}, {round(F_drag[1],2)}     fuel left: {projectile_motion.m_fuel}")
    t+=dt
    return [vx, vy, a[0], a[1]]

projectile_motion.t_prev = t0
sol = solve_ivp(projectile_motion, (t0, tf), [x0, y0, vx0, vy0], t_eval = np.linspace(t0, tf, int((tf-t0)/dt)+1))
y_max = max(sol.y[1])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(sol.y[0], sol.y[1], c='red')
ax.plot(sol.y[0][0], sol.y[1][0], c="#000000", label="start")
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
ax.set_ylim([0, y_max*1.05])

ax.set_xlabel('x (m)')
ax.set_ylabel('y (m)')
ax.set_title('Projectile Trajectory')

if x_of_fuel_out != None:
    print(f"Fuel ran out at x = {x_of_fuel_out}m")
    plt.axvline(x=x_of_fuel_out, linestyle='--')
else:
    print("There was enough fuel.")

if x_hit != None:
    print(f"Range: {x_hit} m")
    ax.set_xlim([0,x_hit])
print(f"max height: {y_max} m")

plt.show()
```

Comment: That is correct, the inner time steps and the output samples are independent. What exactly is the use of t_prev? In most cases this can be resolved as DDE (no solvers in scipy), with the event mechanism of solve_ivp or via an extended ODE system. What of that may apply depends on the details.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. The issue is that the points where plot is supposed to be made are in correct time moments, whereas the function seems to be evaluated with varying timesteps. The problem I face is that I need the dt for the definition of momentum inside the function to be the same (I asked the program to print every t for which it evaluates the expression and as a result, I got varying timesteps). Is there any way that I can deal with it? I added the whole program in the edit